# How open same Activity inside itself?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a HomeActivity which displays a list of clothes and clicking in one of them opens DetailsActivity, which displays its details in the left side. In the right side I show a list of more clothes "you may like these as well:".

After clicking in one of these recommended clothes, I want to open another DetailsActivity on top of the current, and NOT replace its contents.

As so when the user presses the "Back" button, I want to unstack each clothe details before the HomeActivity.

How can I do that? I looked through all Intent flags and don't seen to find a way to do it.

**-= UPDATED =-**

I tried fragments instead of Activities but the stack of the fragments is lost when I rotate the screen.

```
FragmentDetails fDetails = new FragmentDetails();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(FragmentDetails.BILLING_ID, billingId);
fDetails.setArguments(args);
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(android.R.id.content, fDetails, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

And this is the method to open the same Activity, which is not working:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityDetails.class);
intent.putExtra(ActivityDetails.BILLING_ID, billingId);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Why not use fragments?

Comment: Fragments would be best suited !

Comment: I tried with stacking fragments but it showed different problems as I tried to change the device's orientation.

Comment: What kind of "different problems"?

Comment: The stack of fragments wasn't saved after a screen rotation.
As a reference a added both methods to open the Fragment and to open the Activity in my post.

Answer (score 1):

You should be handling this some other way like swapping fragment or just updating view with new data (cloth detail) instead of reopening Activity.

If you really have to then you can start new Activity and finish old one.

```
startActivity(yourIntent);
finish();
```

This way if user presses back, application will go way to main view.

Comment: I really want to stack the DetailsActivity instead of finishing it's instances. I also tried with stacking fragments but it showed different problems as I tried to change the device's orientation.

Comment: then just call startActivity. it should be fine.

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't work. As a reference, this is my method to open the DetailsActivity:

`Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityDetails.class);
i.putExtra(ActivityDetails.BILLING_ID, billingId);
startActivity(i);`